# Naming Conflict Between A Scala Reserved Word And A Field Name of A Hibernate Annotation

Tags: scala

Hibernate has the following annotation

```
@Type(type = "foo")
```

where "type" is a reserved word in Scala. The above code can't get compiled in Scala. I can rename the annotation, but not its field name to my knowledge.

How to solve this naming conflict problem?

Comment: try \`type\`, with backquotes.

Comment: Thanks. That trick works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scala uses ` (backtick, key is in upper left with ~) to denote a previously defined variable when the text would otherwise mean something else.  This is useful in pattern matching or here for a variable name defined as a scala keyword.

```
@Type(`type` = "foo")
```